# Protobuf Gradle plugin version 0.8.6 and higher vs Project 'flutter_blue' is using version 0.8.3

Tags: gradle, flutter

Using:

- VS Code: 1.29.1
- Flutter: 1.0.0
- Flutter_blue: 0.4.1
- Used the flutter_blue/example

When starting the debugger, I got:

```
Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Development\flutter\bluetooth_example\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Configure project :flutter_blue
The com.google.protobuf plugin was already applied to the project: :flutter_blue and will not be applied again after plugin: android-library

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Protobuf Gradle plugin version 0.8.6 and higher. Project 'flutter_blue' is using version 0.8.3.
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a pull request to fix this.

https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/pull/147

This is the change required in the build.gradle file in the flutter_blue package.

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.3' <- Remove
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.6' <-- Add
    }
```

You can do it manually by editing the version to 8.3.6 although you might need to update your minSDK version in the project manifest file too.

Comment: You also need to change android/app/build.gradle and change minSdkVersion from 16 to 19

Answer (score 1):

It works for me to update flutter_blue with a newer protobuf version.
You may change settings under flutter_blue/ just as the following changes --

```
 diff --git a/android/build.gradle b/android/build.gradle index
 cf39349..39b277b 100644
 --- a/android/build.gradle
 +++ b/android/build.gradle @@ -9,7 +9,7 @@ buildscript {

      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
 -        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.3'
 +        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.6'
      }  }
```